# Lipschitz constant and operator norm of derivative in Hilbert spaces

Tags: derivatives, hilbert-spaces, lipschitz-functions

Let $f:X \to Y$ be a mapping between Hilbert spaces satisfying 
$$\frac{f(x+th)-f(x)}{t} \to f'(x)(h)$$
as $t \to 0$, i.e., $f$ is directionally differentiable.

If $f$ is known to be Lipschitz with Lipschitz constant $L$, is it true that
$$L = \lVert{f'(x)}\rVert_{\text{operator}}$$
?

Comment: Not necessarily. Though it's true that $\|f'(x)\|_{\text{operator}} \le L$. See here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2089345/lipschitz-implies-fx-le-d/2089370#2089370

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equality $L = \lVert{f'(x)}\rVert_{\text{operator}}$ does not look plausible, considering the right hand side involves $x$ while the left hand side does not. The correct statement is
$$L = \sup_{x\in X} \lVert{ f'(x) }\rVert_{\text{operator}}$$

Indeed, the inequality $\ge $ follows from 
$$\|f'(t)h\| = \lim_{t\to 0} \frac{\|f(x+th)-f(x)\|}{|t|} \le \frac{L \|th\|}{|t|} = L\|h\|$$
For the reverse inequality, let $M=\sup_{x\in X} \lVert{ f'(x) }\rVert_{\text{operator}}$. Let $\varphi$ be any unit-norm functional on $X$. It suffices to prove that the composition $g = \varphi\circ f$ is $M$-Lipschitz. Let $a,b\in X$ be distinct points, and consider the restriction of $g$ to the line segment $[a,b]$. This is a scalar function of a scalar argument, whose derivative is bounded by $M$. The mean value theorem yields $|g(a)-g(b)|\le M|a-b|$, which proves the claim.

**Remark**: This works for any pair of normed spaces, they don't have to be Hilbert spaces.